# UBUNTU 20.04 LTS. Can't run updates. Says version unsupported

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

I did the upgrade to 20.04 about 4 months ago. I downloaded it from the page that kept sending me upgrade messages, and did a fresh install on my new SSD. All worked well, updating software multiple times in the past few months from South African servers. I am now in North Africa. I tried to load Brother Printer drivers for a DCP-T300. It said I needed to update. Update said it couldn't download from SA server. I the changed to MAIN SERVER. It has given me issues the whole week, finally, on a post, I saw to run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

 This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

---

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  506  Failure To Connect To Web Server [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  506  Failure To Connect To Web Server [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  506  Failure To Connect To Web Server [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  506  Failure To Connect To Web Server [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  506  Failure
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1284347/edit) to show us the complete input and output of a failed update.

Comment: I see no reference in your sources.list to the `main` repo!  If that is truly a complete listing of your sources.list

Comment: @OrganicMarble 
When posting as a newbie without some or other recognition, one is not allowed to post more than 10 links, or something like that. I had to remove more than half of what appeared in the terminal. The first line copied in the post ends with "focal main restricted", which was repeated amongst other lines saying similar "restricted"!

Hopefully, that is what you mean, otherwise, I will need directions!

Comment: @Bugkilla that's good news for your system!  Posting text in the question is not a "link".

Comment: Sorry you ran into that "too many links" issue - to avoid it you just need to format the `sources.list` file contents and APT output as code (see the formatting of the question - the editor has a button with {} on it for this).

Comment: Thank you all. someone suggested either here or elsewhere that it was probably more network related than Ubuntu. I hardwired the laptop to the main satellite router, it increased network speed ever so slightly (clouds cause signal loss). The software and updates connection continually failed, but repeatedly using *sudo apt-get update* allowed it to update in small chunks. Almost done!  Thanks for the help!